# Build all binaries for different Android app stores in a single step

Tags: android, eclipse, build-automation, google-play, amazon-appstore

I currently distribute my Android apps on Android Market, SlideMe and Amazon app store.  Android Market and SlideMe require a signed binary, while Amazon requires an unsigned one.  I also need to differentiate some of the code to be compiled depending on which store I'm targeting.  Currently I only need to display different text/link information, but in the future there may be a need to change things like included libraries.

I am using Eclipse on Windows to build my projects.  I am looking for the easiest way to conditionally compile the code and create multi-target builds as required for each store.

I don't need the builds to be triggered automatically by commits or timers or anything of that nature.  I only need to trigger the builds manually.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Off topic, how do you price the app so you meet the amazon weird price requirements? :)

Comment: Please don't go off topic.  Ask in separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find that [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) will help with this. It supports parameterised builds, plus also matrix builds. Matrix builds multidimensional parameterised builds - you specify a series of sets of values, and every combination is built.

eg:

- Language (US English, UK English, French)
- Appstore (Amazon, Android, SlideMe)

Jenkins would build all the combinations of above.

Obviously you will still need an Ant build script to do the hard work, but I believe Android's SDK has reasonable support for Ant.

Comment: Rich, I've clarified my question.  I don't need the builds to be triggered automatically, which is what Jenkins seems to be for.  I'll be triggering the builds manually.  I've never used Ant, but isn't that all I need to create the targeted builds?

Comment: At this point, I have enough to get started.  I will create an Ant script first, and that will pretty much solve my problem.  I found an excellent tutorial on setting up the Ant script here: http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html

Answer (score 0):

You could just set up a Maven Android Plugin based build for your apk that uses resource filtering and profiles for your different configurations. Check the morseflash example of the official samples project to see how it is all done in detail.

Once you have the profiles set up you can use the maven invoker plugin to run it all in one sweep. And if you want to have it automated just put the build on Hudson.

http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/

http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Samples

http://www.simpligility.com/2010/11/release-version-management-for-your-android-application/